# Animating items in a list

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I made a simple reproduction of my code. I have a list in which I can change item position by clicking **up** & **down** buttons. I wanted to achieve also an animation when changing item's position. So e.g. clicking "up" button should move item by `translateY(-100%)` and the other way around for "down" button.  Tried this on my own but couldnt achieve the result and had a lot of bugs when changing positioning. Whats the best way to do it?

```js
const { useState } = React;

const ITEMS = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"];

const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(ITEMS);

  const handleMoveItem = (index, direction) => {
    const updatedItems = [...items];
    const targetIndex = direction === "up" ? index - 1 : index + 1;

    if (targetIndex >= 0 && targetIndex < items.length) {
      [updatedItems[index], updatedItems[targetIndex]] = [
        updatedItems[targetIndex],
        updatedItems[index],
      ];

      setItems(updatedItems);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <ul>
        {items.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={item}>
            {item}
            <div>
              <button onClick={() => handleMoveItem(index, "up")}>
                up
              </button>
              <button onClick={() => handleMoveItem(index, "down")}>
                down
              </button>
            </div>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
}

ul li {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: lightblue;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding animation to list items in React with vanilla JavaScript can be tricky. You would need to add and remove classes during the reordering of list.

Alternatively, you can use a package `@formkit/auto-animate` to add animation to your list.

Reference: [example](https://codingislove.com/animate-list-reordering-react/#:%7E:text=Using%20auto%2Danimate%20to%20re,element%20will%20be%20auto%2Danimated!)